# An explicit solution to the congruence $x^2\equiv 14(\frac 3p)-(\frac p3)-12\pmod {p}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, congruences, ramanujan

Let $p>3$ be a prime, and let $(\frac{\cdot}p)$ be the Legendre symbol. Then
$$14\left(\frac 3p\right)-\left(\frac p3\right)-12=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\ p\equiv1\pmod{12},
\\-25&\text{if}\ p\equiv5\pmod{12},\\-27&\text{if}\ p\equiv 7\pmod{12},
\\3&\text{if}\ p\equiv 11\pmod{12};\end{cases}$$
this is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. It is interesting to find an **explicit solution** to the congruence
$$x^2\equiv 14\left(\frac 3p\right)-\left(\frac p3\right)-12\pmod p.\tag{1}$$

For $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ define
$$w_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+k}k\binom{2k}k\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}(-8)^{n-k}.$$
I have the following conjectures related to the congruence equation $(1)$.

**Conjecture 1.**  (i) For every $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, the number
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(4k+1)48^{n-1-k}w_k$$
is a positive integer.

(ii) For any prime $p>3$ we have
$$\bigg(\frac1p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{4k+1}{(-48)^k}w_k\bigg)^2\equiv 14\left(\frac 3p\right)-\left(\frac p3\right)-12\pmod p.\tag{2}$$

**Conjecture 2.** We have the identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4k+1}{(-48)^k}w_k=\frac{\sqrt{72+42\sqrt3}}{\pi}.\tag{3}$$

**Conjecture 3.** For any prime $p>3$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{w_k}{(-48)^k}\equiv\begin{cases}4x^2-2p\pmod{p^2}&\text{if}\ p=x^2+4y^2\ (x,y\in\mathbb Z),\\0\pmod{p^2}&\text{if}\ p\equiv3\pmod 4.\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

**QUESTION.** How to solve the above three conjectures? In particular, how to prove the congruence $(2)$?

Your comments are welcome!